# Keep Jupyter Notebook TQDM output after detaching tmux session

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tmux, tqdm

I am running a jupyter notebook within a tmux session. The Jupyter Notebook uses a simple countdown timer and tqdm progress bar to test if I can detach the tmux session and retain the tqdm output.

Here is how I set up the tmux session:

```
tmux new-session -s mysession
```

Then I open a Jupyter Notebook within the tmux session

```
jupyter notebook
```

Create a .ipynb notebook with the following test code:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

with tqdm(total=10000) as pbar:
    for i in range(10000):
        time.sleep(1)
        pbar.update(1)
    
print('DONE')
```

Once this is running, I can see the counter and progress bar:

[image]

Now detach the session and close the open Jupyter Notebook browser tabs

```
Ctrl-b d
```

Reopen the Jupyter Notebook in browser with tmux session detached

```
http://localhost:8888/?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

When I reopen the browser, the Jupyter Notebook is running, although the tqdm output is stopped at wherever I closed the Jupyter Notebook browser windows.

Is there a way to keep output such as tqdm progress bar information running when reopening a Jupyter Notebook from a detached tmux session?